# MySQL Bulk Insert Dependent on Another Table

Tags: mysql

I have a case where I'm doing two queries: `query1` is a bulk `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` on `table1`. For `query2`, I want to do another bulk `INSERT` on `table2` with some application data along with using the ids inserted/updated from `query1`. I know I can do this with an intermediate query, selecting the ids I need from `table1` and then inserting them into `table2` along with application data, but I really want to avoid the extra network back-and-forth of that query along with the db overhead. Is there any way I can either get the ids inserted/updated from `query1` when running that, or do some kind of complex, but relatively less expensive `INSERT ... SELECT FROM` in `query2` to avoid this?

As far as I know, getting ids added/modified returned from `query1` is impossible without a separate query, and I can't think of a way to batch `INSERT ... SELECT FROM` where the insertion values for each row are dependent on the selected value, but I'd love to be proven wrong, or shown a way around either of those.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get a set of IDs as a result of a bulk `INSERT`.

One option you have is indeed to run a `SELECT` query to get the IDs and use them in the second bulk `INSERT`. But that's a hassle.

Another option is to run the 2nd bulk `INSERT` into a *temporary* table, let's call it `table3`, then use `INSERT INTO table2 ... SELECT FROM ... table1 JOIN table3 ...`

With a similar use case we eventually found that this is the fastest option, given that you index `table3` correctly.
Note that in this case you don't have a `SELECT` that you need to loop over in your code, which is nice.